# What is the word that means a 'what if' phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that means a 'what if' phrase?

In a college course, I vaguely remember, the instructor wrote a word on the board that loosely meant or perhaps described any sentence that was a what-if statement. If I remember correctly it was essentially a word for classes of phrases, like say an appositive phrase. It was a more technical word, not something common like hypothetical, and for the life of me I can't recall it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Hypothetical?"

Comment: I think they are called ***suppositions***, making assumptions or guesses without credible proof at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'counterfactual' may be what you have in mind. It is applied not only to questions--'counterfactual questions' often begin with "what if ..."--but also assertions, the 'counterfactual conditional' statement, and a type of reasoning, 'counterfactual reasoning'.

A general definition of the adjective is presented along with an example of the use of 'counterfactual question' at *The Free Dictionary*:

> coun·ter·fac·tu·al  (koun′tər-făk′cho͞o-əl) *adj.*
>   Running contrary to the facts: "Cold war historiography vividly illustrates how the selection of the *counterfactual question* to be asked generally anticipates the desired answer" (Timothy Garton Ash).

[counterfactual. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved January 13 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/counterfactual .]

For examples and discussion of 'counterfactual reasoning' and 'counterfactual conditional', see ["Causal Explanations in Counterfactual Reasoning"](http://www.qrg.northwestern.edu/papers/Files/QRG_Dist_Files/QRG_2009/final.pdf), M. Dehghani, R. Iliev, and S. Kaufmann, in *Proceedings of the 31st Annual Conference of the Cognitive Science Society*, 2009.

Comment: That's the one! It was rattling around somewhere in my brain and I just couldn't grasp it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[spec•u•la•tion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/speculation) (ˌspɛk yəˈleɪ ʃən)

n.

1. the contemplation or consideration of some subject.
2. a single instance or process of consideration.
3. a conclusion or opinion reached by such contemplation.
4. conjectural consideration of a matter; conjecture or surmise.
5. engagement in commercial transactions that involve risk with the hope of profiting as a result of market fluctuations.

*Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*

[spec·u·late](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/speculate)  (spĕk′yə-lāt′)
v. spec·u·lat·ed, spec·u·lat·ing, spec·u·lates

v.intr.

1. To engage in a course of reasoning often based on inconclusive evidence; conjecture or theorize.
2. To engage in the buying or selling of a commodity with an element of risk on the chance of profit.

v.tr.

To assume to be true without conclusive evidence: speculated that high cholesterol was a contributing factor to the patient's health problems.

[Latin speculārī, speculāt-, to observe, from specula, watchtower, from specere, to look at; see spek- in Indo-European roots.]

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*

Adjective: [Speculative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/speculative).

---

[con·jec·ture](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conjecture)  (kən-jĕk′chər)

n.

1. Opinion or judgment based on inconclusive or incomplete evidence; guesswork.
2. An opinion or conclusion based on guesswork: The commentators made various conjectures about the outcome of the next election.

v. con·jec·tured, con·jec·tur·ing, con·jec·tures

v.tr.

To judge or conclude by conjecture; guess: "From the comparative silence below ... I conjectured that Mr Rochester was now at liberty" (Charlotte Brontë).

v.intr.

To make a conjecture.

[Middle English, from Old French, from Latin coniectūra, from coniectus, past participle of conicere, to infer : com-, com- + iacere, to throw; see yē- in Indo-European roots.]

- con·jec′tur·a·ble adj.
- con·jec′tur·al adj.
- con·jec′tur·al·ly adv.
- con·jec′tur·er n.

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*

Answer (score 0):

The [subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) refers to "various states of unreality" (wikipedia).